# How can I repurpose the fields of a base class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to design a nodal class that I can then use for various types of trees, but I run into complications when I try to consider how to do it in such a way that I don't create unnecessary fields. For example, I have the following class:

```
class Node {
protected:
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
}
```

This class will have methods which will deal with getting and setting the left and right connections of the node. But then, I also will have the next class:

```
class BinaryNode : public Node { 
protected:
    BinaryNode *left_child;
    BinaryNode *right_child;
    BinaryNode *parent;
}
```

Aside from the new parent connection, the left and right child nodes can be described using the left and right connections from the base class, but I can't use them because they are not binary nodes. Is there an appropriate way to repurpose them to behave in the way I want?

I also occurred to me that it may not be worth the effort, and that I should be creating the new fields anyway, so that I am not forced to drag the sometimes unintuitive names and suspicious casting. I would welcome an opinion on this thought.

Comment: ***but I can't use them because they are not binary nodes.*** You can since BinaryNode is a Node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the suggested class hierarchy, `BinaryNode` would have four children. Left and right generic nodes from the base, and left and right binary nodes as direct members.

Unless you need dynamic polymorphism, a template would be an appropriate way to reuse node code. This is a typical use case for Curiously Recurring Template Pattern:

```
template<class Child>
class Node {
protected:
    Child *left;
    Child *right;
};

class BinaryNode : protected Node<BinaryNode> { 
protected:
    BinaryNode *parent;
};
```